# not exit key in dictionary

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary, aiogram

I have a dictionary and when I want to use it in my code I cant find any key with given key. but key is exist my code.
also it save duplicate key in my dictionary because it not recognize my key in dictionary

```
profile_account={"3286686": {"password": "hjhljjlllllllllll", "username": "oubbbbb", "trader_code":
0, "bot_code": 0, "addres_wallet": "", "state_user": "-", "expire_Data": "", 
"telegram_username": "future0bot", "Register": true, "trader": false, "is_bot": false}, 
"3286686": {"password": "ryyyyyyyyyy", "username": "urmuyr", "trader_code": 0, 
"bot_code": 0, "addres_wallet": "", "state_user": "-", "expire_Data": "", 
"telegram_username": "future0bot", "Register": true, "trader": false, "is_bot": false}}
```

also when I print them in my code I get this result

```
print(profile_account)
print(message.from_id,[*profile_account])
print(message.from_id not in profile_account)

output:

{'328660186': {'password': 'ryyyyyyyyyy', 'username': 'urmuyr', 'trader_code': 0,
'bot_code': 0, 'addres_wallet': '', 'state_user': '-', 'expire_Data': '', 
'telegram_username': 'future0bot', 'Register': True, 'trader': False, 'is_bot': False}}
328660186 ['328660186']
True
```

also I dump and load this dictionary with below method

```
json.dump(profile_account, open('profile_account.json', 'w'))
profile_account = json.load(open('profile_account.json'))
```

Comment: The `profile_account` object on the top is an invalid mix between a Python dictionary and a JSON object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's because the `message.from_id` variable is an `integer` variable type and your dictionary keys are the `string`.
you have to convert them to a same type, like :

```py
from_id = str(message.from_id)
print(profile_account[from_id])
```